# Como retornar multiplos parametros de um nome Api Ruby com Faraday

Tags: api, ruby-on-rails, ruby, característica-linguagem

Ola, tenho uma dúvida de como retornar multiplos parametros de um atributo em uma api.
já tentei concatenar utilizando o | e  %df mas não consegui. Ele só aceita um nome e imprime corretamente, quando eu faço um gets.chomp com dois nomes, não funciona.

```
  def self.frequencia_decadas
    puts 'Digite o nome para obter a frequencia por décadas'
    nome = gets.chomp
    response = Faraday.get("https://servicodados.ibge.gov.br/api/v2/censos/nomes/#{nome}")
    json = JSON.parse(response.body, symbolize_names: true)
    json.map do |decadas|
    @decadas = decadas[:res].map do |frequencia|
    @frequencia = nome, frequencia[:frequencia], frequencia[:periodo]
    end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

Olhe, o problema não é o código ruby apenas, mas a API em si.

esta API aceita mais de um nome separado por `|`

[https://servicodados.ibge.gov.br/api/v2/censos/nomes/fernando|maria](https://servicodados.ibge.gov.br/api/v2/censos/nomes/fernando%7Cmaria)

neste caso, você precisa codificar o caracter `|` que em HTML seria `%7C`

voce pode saber mais sobre encoding aqui
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.ASP

mas você pode contar com `URI.encode` para encodar suar URIs

aqui está um exemplo

```rb
require 'faraday'
require 'json'
require 'pry-nav'

def teste
  nomes = []
  loop do
    puts 'Digite o nome para obter a frequencia por décadas (pressione enter para finalizar)'
    nome = gets.chomp

    break if nome == ""
    nomes << nome
  end

  busca = nomes.join("|")
  uri = "https://servicodados.ibge.gov.br/api/v2/censos/nomes/#{busca}"
  final_uri = URI.encode(uri)

  response = Faraday.get(final_uri)
  json = JSON.parse(response.body, symbolize_names: true)
  puts json.map { |entry| entry[:nome] }
end

teste
```